# How can I effectively version control and deploy a 3rd-party Rails web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment

Deploying your own Rails app is fairly straightforward. However, I've found that trying to keep a 3rd-party Rails app under version control and deployed has been quite painful.

Suppose I want to take an existing RoR application (in my case it's Redmine, but this could apply to any app, even beyond Rails), and deploy it on my (traditional) hosting server. I want to ensure I can undo any change I make to the configuration or local customizations, but I also want to be able to routinely upgrade to the latest version.

The public git repository for Redmine has a `.gitignore` file that covers things like the config yaml files and session store. This makes sense for development, but certainly not for deployment.

It seems like I have a few options:

1. Unignore config files in my copy of the official repo, and add my customizations, plugins, etc. I can then merge new versions to my branch and deal with the conflicts.
2. Keep a local repository with no history from the official repository. Merging new versions will be completely manual.
3. Do something a lot more complicated. Multiple levels of branches/repositories?

None of these options seem particularly elegant or simple to me, and so I've thus far taken the easy route: do nothing.

This seems like it would be a common issue but I wasn't able to find any blogs or questions that really covered this. How do you deal with deploying a 3rd-party web application?

Answer (score 0):

Some options are:

#### Use [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki) for deployments.

There are lots of tutorials for running db migrations with capistrano, and you can keep it all in git

#### Use [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/puppet-open-source/) or [chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) to do your migrations.

This has the advantage of being able to set up and run all kinds of deployments, including adding servers, etc

#### Secret Sauce: Continuous Deployment

Use a single place to perform these migrations, automatically.

Set up a CI server (ex: [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)) which watches the repository upstream (`origin` or `live` or whatever) and performs the migrations committed there. Also, Jenkins can be set up to watch for rollbacks in the repo, and perform the complimentary downward migration *before* copying the updated code.

#### CI is too big?

If a CI setup is overkill, there are git hosting/deployment services out there that do a nice job in the middle. I use [Springloops](http://www.springloops.com/v2/) for simple deployments, and a REST hook to perform database migrations on every deployment. Unfortunately, it only really works for 'up' migrations, 'down' migrations are still done by hand.

Comment: I am aware of these tools (though more familiar with Fabric, as a python developer). However, I'm looking for specifics on how to deal with versioning configuration files, while still working off the original development repo and being able to upgrade.

Comment: These are tools specifically *for* dealing with configuration files, and made to be used under version control. Not sure what I'm missing?

Comment: You've addressed only a tiny portion of the question. What about the whole aspect of dealing with an upstream repository? I'm currently rolling my own solution and I'll post it in a few days. Basically, I'm using fabric to deploy and sync config files from a separate git repository. The main issue is you have to follow a specific sequence to not mess things up.